# retrieve text from the HTML source page using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium

My HTML page looks like this :

```
<div id="s-resultlist-header" class="s-resultlist-header" style="width: 607px;">
  <div class="s-resultlist-hits">
    <span>Total hits: 203</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to retrieve a value "Total hits: 203" within the span into a variable. I need to validate if total results is equal to 203. Language used: Python.

I have tried:

```
elem = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(//div[@class='s-resultlist-hits']span
```

but gives a error: Expected `).` Can anyone correct the syntax?

I have also tried:

```
print browser.pagesource
```

But it prints the entire page source. Can anyone guide?

Comment: Please show us the whole code and Exception.

Comment: It looks like the error is a syntax error because you're missing a closing `)`. Try it with the closing `)`.

Comment: @Chris I have tried 
elem = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='s-resultlist-header']//div[@class='s-resultlist-hits']//span")
But i get error u'Unable to locate element:{"method":"xpath","selector":"

Answer (score 1):

```
elem = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='s-resultlist-header']/div[@class='s-resultlist-hits']/span");
```

Comment: @Fabio There is no exception,but I just want to retrieve text instead of page
try:
             self.assertTrue(self.verifytext("Total hits: 203"))
             text = self.browser.page_source
             print text
            elem = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='s-resultlist-header']/div[@class='s-resultlist-hits']/span")
             print elem
             "stop"
        except AssertionError as e:self.fail(self,msg=None)
    def verifytext(self,string):
        if str(string) in self.browser.page_source:return True
        else:return False

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried the above solution suggested by you ,but I get a error
u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":
; Stacktrace: Method newInstance0 threw an error in None

Comment: Please bare with the syntax of text , as Ima still new to this forum , and might have missed rules for replying comments